# Does file_get_contents / curl use browsers ip or servers ip?

Tags: php, xml, curl, ip, file-get-contents

I'm currently sampling an xml feed that is restricted to certain ip addresses.  I had my personal ip address green lighted and I was able to access the feed through my browser and in turn file_get_contents was able to access the feed when run off my localhost.

I moved the site to the production server, whose ip address is supposed to be green lighted for the feed(im having them double check) and now the same file get contents is no longer working.  I'm currently triggering the file_get_contents though by accessing a certain url from my browser though, which I'll be changing after I verify that the feed is working.  Since I trigger it from my browser I'm wondering if its using the wrong ip somehow.

I've tried this both with curl and file_get_contents now though and am getting the same result, a 401 unauthorized back from the server providing the feed so i'm thinking the feed company might just not have the production servers ip added to the green light list yet.

Is there anything special I'm missing that would need to be implemented on the production server that wouldn't on my localhost that might be preventing me access to the feed?

Comment: You could be going through a proxy. That would result in your IP being at the receiving end not being what you expect it to be.

Comment: @SDC any ideas how to detect that?  I'm going to check the phpinfo() for starters.

Comment: ya the addresss dumped as the server ip is definitely different than the one I get if I just run an ip check on the domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request is made from the server, so it'll use the server's IP.